# Auto open macro fails after renaming file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file that has an auto_open macro that launches another macro called OpenFIles.  I had to save the file under another name because the file only opened in read-only mode when I was working through the company VPN.  If the renamed file is already open the file I can run the OpenFiles macro but when I open the file the auto_open macro gives me an error message that the macro may not be available or all macros are  disabled.  I have the same security setting as the original file.  I would go back to my original file but I have done too much in the new file.  Please help.  The code is:

```
Sub LauncMacro()
  Auto_Open Macro
  Application.Run "FWorking.xlsb!OpenFiles"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is Vb.Net or VBA from Excel?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub LauncMacro()
  Auto_Open Macro
  Application.Run "FWorking.xlsb!OpenFiles"
End Sub
```

I think your problem is the use of **FWorking** in `Application.Run "FWorking.xlsb!OpenFiles"` if the workbook is no longer called **FWorking** it won't be able to find and execute the macro.

maybe you could try:

`Application.Run thisworkbook.name & "!OpenFiles"`

or just use

`Application.Run "OpenFiles"`

Comment: Fworking is the new name so it should have worked.  I will try the other suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: Application.Run "OpenFiles" works if you manually run it after the file is open but it doesn't launch automatically when you open the file.  The other one did not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: why not put "OpenFiles" in your *Workbook_Open* event handler in the **ThisWorkbook** class module?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it only works with Auto_Open as the name of the macro.  I re-recorded the macro with name of Open_Macro and it worked.